# Oracle Script for target table

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have the following requirement

In Table A

```
CRD  | RNo  | J_NAME
-------------------------
DOS1 |1     | NULL
DOS2 |2     | Name 1
DOS3 |3     | Name 2
DOS4 |4     | Name 3
DOS5 |5     | Name 1
DOS6 |6     | Name 1
DOS7 |7     | Name 4
DOS8 |8     | Name 2
```

Out put should be

```
CRD  | RNo  | J_NAME
-------------------------
DOS1 |1     | NULL
DOS2 |2     | A
DOS3 |3     | B
DOS4 |4     | C
DOS5 |5     | A
DOS6 |6     | A
DOS7 |7     | D
DOS8 |8     | B
```

Null allays should be null, If the name already exist in the target table then It will be add the same name eg: J_Name = A and B, if the source value is not in the target table then it will get a new entry from the list.

Ho I can achieve this?

Comment: Why does Name 1 become A? What's the logic?

Comment: **any thing you tried so far......??** :\

Comment: `outer join` the target table `ON` name, and select the name from it. But the new entry from list? I don't get that..

Comment: you want to update and insert at the same time - is that correct? have you considered "merge"

Comment: Yes I wanted to insert and update same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT CRD, RNo, 
CASE WHEN J_NAME ='Name 1' THEN 'A'
WHEN J_NAME ='Name 2' THEN 'B'
WHEN J_NAME ='Name 3' THEN 'C'
WHEN J_NAME ='Name 4' THEN 'D' 
ELSE 'NULL' END AS J_NAME
FROM TAB;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you won't run out of letters (since you're not telling how to generate values beyond `Z`), you could just dense_rank your names and give them a letter corresponding to the rank;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT * FROM mytable UNION ALL SELECT '', 0, NULL FROM DUAL
)
SELECT crd, rno, CASE WHEN j_name IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CHR(calc+63) END j_name
FROM (
  SELECT crd, rno, j_name, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY j_name NULLS FIRST) calc
  FROM cte
)
WHERE rno > 0 ORDER BY rno;
```

It basically takes the table contents, adds a row with a null `J_NAME` value to make sure there's a rank for NULL, and uses `DENSE_RANK()` on the resulting j_names to get a value to generate the letter from.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/744af/1).

Comment: my requirement is to make a fake entry in to the table for J_name and rno is a varchar data type